# Easy way to see saved NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsuserdefaults

Is there a way to see what's been saved to `NSUserDefaults` directly?  I'd like to see if my data saved correctly.

Comment: Use this to get the location of your apps directory: print(NSHomeDirectory()) from that location, go to Library>Preferences><yourAppsBundleName.plist> this will be where NSUserDefaults is saving your data.

Comment: Using XCode 12.3 on Catalina UserDefaults.plist is visible in project resources but does not contain preferences values.

Comment: The file suggested by Bobby is in a hidden folder  not visible to Finder unless hidden items are shown by clicking cmd-shift-period

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You can find the pList file for your app in the simulator if you go to:

/users/*your user name*/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<Sim Version>/Applications

This directory has a bunch of GUID named directories.  If you are working on a few apps there will be a few of them.  So you need to find your app binary:

```
find . -name foo.app
./1BAB4C83-8E7E-4671-AC36-6043F8A9BFA7/foo.app
```

Then go to the Library/Preferences directory in the GUID directory.  So:

```
cd 1BAB4C83-8E7E-4671-AC35-6043F8A9BFA7/Library/Preferences
```

You should find a file that looks like:

```
<Bundle Identifier>.foo.pList
```

Open this up in the pList editor and browse persisted values to your heart's content.

Comment: I've found this has changed in later versions of XCode. You'll now find it in a directory under the current ios version number instead of User - eg /users/your user name/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications

Comment: Interesting... It seems that if you're doing OCMock / SenTestingKit unit testing with `NSUserDefaults`, then the `NSUserDefaults` aren't persisted to a .plist file but rather managed in memory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193597/where-does-ocunit-store-nsuserdefaults

Comment: How can I view it for an already installed application? My client downloaded the application from the appstore, and something is wrong. I need to check the NSUserDefaults file

Comment: Your client - if you can talk to him and he somewhat savvy - could use a tool like PhoneView to get access to his phones filesystem and copy the file off the phone to send it to you.

Comment: For those people wanting to get access to the folder in the simulator, see Jeff's answer below about SimPholders - a great little app to find the folder easily for you: https://simpholders.com/
I have no connection to the author of the app at all, but it is very useful.

Comment: What if my simulator version in not there. I am using latest Xcode 7.2 iOS SDK 9.2

Comment: The path has changed to: ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices

Comment: @Kyll sorry for the mistake.I understood :)

Comment: I have no `~/Library` (`/Users/<me>/Library`) folder

Comment: (on macOS Sierra)

Comment: In Xcode 10, the plist file seems to have non of the keys set in `UserDefault.standard`...

Answer (score 361):

You can print all current NSUserDefaults to the log:

Just keys:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys]);
```

Keys and values:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

Comment: THX, this one is more efficient~

Comment: Apple could make a simple viewer in XCode for this. Like the plist viewer. But no, they don't want to make it easy.

Answer (score 85):

## In Swift we can use the following:-

## Swift 3.x & 4.x

#### For getting all keys & values:

```
for (key, value) in UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation() {
    print("\(key) = \(value) \n")
}
```

#### For retrieving the complete dictionary representation of user defaults:

```
print(Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()))
```

#### For retrieving the keys:

```
// Using dump since the keys are an array of strings.
dump(Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys))
```

#### For retrieving the values:

We can use dump here as well, but that will return the complete inheritance hierarchy of each element in the values array. If more information about the objects is required, then use dump, else go ahead with the normal print statement.

```
// dump(Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().values))
print(Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().values))
```

## Swift 2.x

#### For retrieving the complete dictionary representation of user defaults:

```
print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation())
```

#### For retrieving the keys:

```
print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys.array)
```

#### For retrieving the values:

```
print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().values.array)
```

Answer (score 40):

You can check the values for each key in the array, returned by

```
[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys]
```

Comment: This worked in the debugger too by using this command: (lldb) "po [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys]"

Answer (score 23):

I sometimes use the following snippet to print out the location of my NSUserDefaults file when running in the simulator

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
   NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *folder = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"Your NSUserDefaults are stored in this folder: %@/Preferences", folder);
```

It yields the path to the preferences folder

> Your NSUserDefaults are stored in this folder: /Users/castle/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/BC5056A0-F46B-4AF1-A6DC-3A7DAB984960/Library/Preferences

Your NSUserDefaults file is located in the preferences folder and named according to your prefix and appliation name e.g.

```
dk.castleandersen.dreamteam.grid.plist
```

I expect the same to be true for the actual device.

Comment: i like this response. It's stable and will always work, hopefully!

Answer (score 9):

Easy, since the plist file name is `<app-bundle-identifier>.plist`, you can use `find` command to find its path. But it will take very long if you search your whole computer, so you have to pick a good scope, like `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator` for Xcode 6.

example:

`find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator -type f -name com.awesome.app.plist`

the output will be something like this...

`/Users/hlung/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B61913F6-7D7C-4E45-AE2F-F45220A71823/data/Containers/Data/Application/E4CC51CF-11E5-4168-8A74-6BAE3B89998F/Library/Preferences/com.awesome.app.plist`

And from there you can use `open` command. Or if you use **iTerm2**, just command-click on the path to open it.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 4.0

```
//func dictionaryRepresentation() -> [String : AnyObject]
```

because dictionaryRepresentation of NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() returns **[String : AnyObject]**

We cast it into an `NSDictionary`. Then by surrounding it in parenthesis '()' will allow us to to call .allKeys or .allValues just as you would on any NSDictionary

```
 print((UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation() as NSDictionary).allKeys)
```

Answer (score 7):

Use below code.

```
NSLog(@"NSUserDefault: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Interesting how the best answers are usually the shortest.  Rarely is navigating directories in terminal mode necessary.  Evidently, the geeks like the back door approach, maybe the secret hacker in them?

Comment: Thanks, But cant getting you. What you want to say?

Answer (score 6):

For **OS X applications**, instead of finding the application's defaults plist file, it is simpler to use the `defaults` command line utility.

> **NAME**
>
> ```
>  defaults -- access the Mac OS X user defaults system
> ```
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>  defaults [-currentHost | -host hostname] read [domain [key]]
>
>  defaults [-currentHost | -host hostname] read-type domain key
>
>  defaults [-currentHost | -host hostname] write domain { 'plist' | key 'value' }
>
>  defaults [-currentHost | -host hostname] rename domain old_key new_key
>
>  defaults [-currentHost | -host hostname] delete [domain [key]]
>
>  defaults [-currentHost | -host hostname] { domains | find word | help }
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `defaults` allows users to read, write, and delete Mac OS X user defaults from a command-line shell. Mac
>   OS X applications and other programs use the defaults system to record user preferences and other
>   information that must be maintained when the applications aren't running (such as default font for new
>   documents, or the position of an Info panel). Much of this information is accessible through an appli-
>   cation's Preferences panel, but some of it isn't, such as the position of the Info panel. You can
>   access this information with `defaults`

Example:

```
$ defaults read com.apple.Safari
{
    AutoplayPolicyWhitelistConfigurationUpdateDate = "2018-08-24 17:33:48 +0000";
    AutoplayQuirksWhitelistConfigurationUpdateDate = "2018-08-24 17:33:48 +0000";
    DefaultBrowserPromptingState2 = 4;
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

For Xcode 7

NSUserDefaults **standardDefaults** are stored here:

`/Users/{USER}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{UUID}/data/Containers/Data/Application/{UUID}`

NSUserDefaults for **a suite/app group** are stored here:

`/Users/{USER}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{UUID}/data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/{UUID}/Library/Preferences/{GROUP_NAME}.plist`

I would recommend using https://github.com/scinfu/NCSimulatorPlugin because these days everything is behind UUIDs and are a pain to find. It allows easy access to your simulator app directories.

Answer (score 2):

I built this method based on Morion's suggestion for better presentation. Use it by calling `[self logAllUserDefaults]`

```
- (void) logAllUserDefaults
{
    NSArray *keys = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys];
    NSArray *values = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allValues];
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.count; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@: %@", [keys objectAtIndex:i], [values objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you call that function "logAllUserDefaults" since it doesn't actually "get" the defaults?

Comment: Right, @markrickert. Maybe one could create a dictionary from it and return it, then.

Comment: Or simply.. `NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] debugDescription]);` (Almost as in the top-voted answer above.)

Answer (score 2):

Look for the Mac app called **SimPholders2**.  It lives in the menu bar, and lists all of the simulators you've used, and then shows each of your apps.  Select one and you get a new Finder window, already open to the app's directory.  This makes it super easy to find your app and all of it's directories.  It's a **huge time saver** (and I readily donated to the author).

Answer (score 2):

## Simulator App

This shell script search for the **name** of the app, obtain the **bundle id**, and **open folders containing the Plist files**.

```
#!/bin/bash

appname="$1"
[ -z $appname ] && read -p "Application name : " appname

apppath=$(find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ -name "$appname.app" -print -quit)
if [[ ! -z $apppath ]]; then
    appbundle=$(osascript -e "id of app \"$apppath\"")
    find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ -name "$appbundle.plist" -exec bash -c 'open "$(dirname "$1")"' -- {} \;
else
    echo "No application found by that name: $appname.app"
fi
```

#### Extended script version

**Usage:** `iphone-app-folder "My App"`

```
#!/bin/bash
appname="$1"
[ -z "$appname" ] && read -p "Application name : " appname

apppath=$(find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices -name "$appname.app" -print -quit)
if [[ ! -z $apppath ]]; then
    appbundle=$(osascript -e "id of app \"$apppath\"")
    echo "Found app $appname (${appbundle})"
    echo -e "\033[1;30m$apppath\033[0m"
    plists=$(find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices -name "$appbundle.plist" -print -quit)
    count=$(echo plists | wc -l | sed "s/ //g")
    if [[ $count -eq 1 ]] && [[ -f "$plists" ]]; then
        echo -e "\033[1;32mUserDefaults found for $appname\033[0m"
        echo -e "\033[1;30m$plists\033[0m"
        plistutil -i "$plists"
        /usr/bin/open $(dirname "$plists")
    elif [[ ${#plists} -gt 0 ]]; then
        echo -e "\033[1;32mUserDefaults found for $appname\033[0m"
        i=1
        while read line; do
            echo "[${i}] ${line} "
            i=$((i+1))
        done < <(echo "$plists")
        echo
        read -p "Select defaults to read: [1-${count}] " choice
        plist=$(echo ${plists} | sed -n "${choice}p")
        plistutil -i "$plist"
        /usr/bin/open $(dirname "$plist")
    else
        echo -e "\033[31mNo UserDefaults plist found for $appname\033[0m"
    fi
else
    echo -e "\033[31mNo application found by that name: $appname.app\033[0m"
fi
```

> Found app My App (com.organisation.MyApp)
>   /Users/organisation/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3E4C8DC3-6FF4-428F-A624-B78DBE0B8C83/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/960A5232-219D-4C46-8CA3-01E259D8DDAD/My App.app
>
> UserDefaults found for My App

## Mac App

```
defaults read com.bundleid.app
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2.2

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let folder = path[0]
NSLog("Your NSUserDefaults are stored in this folder: \(folder)/Preferences")
```

will print out NSUserDefaults's plist file folder location in Xcode debug console. Copy  the path string. Open your Finder, select Go to Folder in Go menu item, Paste the path string. Double click the plist file. You will see the contents in your Xcode editor.

Only work in Simulator

Thanks @Niels Castle

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for finding the userdefaults plist on simulator for xcode 9.4

Answer (score 2):

> Swift 5 Xcode 11.2 Solution

This is the whole path where your UserDefaults key values will be in a plist file. Follow and find your app bundle identifier .plist file.

> /Users/'Your User Name'/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4176EED3-B9FC-4C77-A25E-ASD201B9FDFG2/data/Containers/Data/Application/56D7CE31-9A8B-4371-9B0F-9604E239423B0/Library/Preferences

Here "4176EED3-B9FC-4C77-A25E-ASD201B9FDFG2" is your Device ID

and "56D7CE31-9A8B-4371-9B0F-9604E239423B0" is your Application ID

I normally get them by sorting folders by last Date Modified in Finder. And most recent edited folder is my device ID and App ID.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I keep a shortcut on my desktop to the simulator's folder where it keeps the apps, ie:

```
/Users/gary/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications
```

Sorted by most recent date, then just go into the most recent app folder Library/Preferences and view the file in the plist editor.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation())
```

Answer (score 1):

**For MacOS apps**
Go to: /Users/{User}/Library/Containers/com.{your company}.{your app}/Data/Library/Preferences and open your app's pList with Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You could NSLog each value you set, like:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] stringForKey:@"WhateverTheKeyYouSet"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading this question's accepted answer, I put together this simple script that opens the plist files used by the iOS simulator to store the `NSUserDefaults` preferences, and while it assumes a certain setup (fits mine perfectly), it may work as a starting point for others.

```
$ cat open-prefs-plist.sh
#!/bin/sh

# The project name based on the workspace path, e.g. "MyProject" from "./MyProject.xcworkspace"
WORKSPACE_NAME=$(echo `find . -name *.xcworkspace -type d -exec basename {} \;` | cut -d'.' -f1)
SIMULATOR_PATH="$HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator"
# The App's bundle ID taken from its info plist, e.g "com.myproject" from "./MyProject/MyProject-Info.plist"
BUNDLE_ID=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier $WORKSPACE_NAME/$WORKSPACE_NAME"-Info.plist"`
# Open all plist files in the simulator path that match the app's bundle ID 
# normally one per iOS version
find "$SIMULATOR_PATH" -name $BUNDLE_ID".plist" -type f -print0 \
    | while IFS= read -r -d '' PLIST; do
    echo $PLIST
    open "$PLIST"
done
```

Example placement:

```
$ ls -1
MyProject
MyProject Tests
MyProject.xcodeproj
MyProject.xcworkspace
Podfile
open-prefs-plist.sh
```

Comment: How do I eat this script, with forks or with hands? where do I put it, I mean?

Comment: @Josh You have to put it alongside your project files (in my example the script is named open-prefs-plist.sh). I've not tested this with the latest Xcode though. I recommend you Flex to inspect this info now. https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX

Answer (score 0):

You can user this to get the full path on user preferences, cache and many other data

`print(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true))`

Answer (score 0):

You can print out the path for the preferences directory from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` callback in your AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .preferencePanesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!)
    return true
}
```

Then you can look at the plist file directly to see what's saved in there.

Answer (score 0):

It will work on upper version SWIFT 4

just put that code in AppDelegate's any method and set breakpoint there

```
**> let path =
> NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory,
> FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true).first**
```

when you run a project, print "path" and you will get path to reach info.plist with userdefaults
Then just go to finder and paste that path
you are reached on that file

Answer (score 0):

for users looking to find the new location for preference stored in the simulator.
This is where I find the values stored.

```
/Users/vikas/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CE5A0444-BD98-4FEE-A839-92728D6E9895/data/Containers/Data/Application/F7430839-ED2C-408A-8A8E-FE7FFAABA8E2/Library/Preferences
```

since we can see there are big identifiers that are hard to guess from the terminal so I would suggest searching for them in your terminal or finder.

the file name should end with **{bundle id}.plist** for example `com.sellerbuddy.online.plist` so you can just head to terminal and hit enter something like below with your app bundle identifier.

```
find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices -type f -name "com.sellerbuddy.online.plist"
```

[image]