# How to manually read from iPhone preferences?

Tags: iphone

I just wrote a few values to my user preferences using `NSUserDefaults`.  Is there a way I can go in and examine the persisted preferences file manually (when running on the simulator) to make sure they were written properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See related: [Easy way to see saved NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676938/easy-way-to-see-saved-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

NSString *text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"***ValueName***"];
NSLog(@"%@",text);