# How to check if NSUserDefaults exist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I have been looking for an answer but not really found what i am looking for.

I have an application and is using NSUserDefaults to store 'currentGameStatus' and would like to ask the following questions:

1. How do i check if the NSUserDefaults .plist exists? Need this to determine if i need to create it for the first time and if so fill it with default values
2. Where do i find it on my Mac (running simulator)? Would need to delete it to test if the first run works?

Comment: In terms of your second question, see the existing [Easy way to see saved NSUserDefaults?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676938/easy-way-to-see-saved-nsuserdefaults) question/answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I do it is I set a `BOOL` flag in `NSUserDefaults` if it doesn't already exist:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"firstRun"]) {
   //do initialization stuff here...

   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"firstRun"];
}
```

Comment: what if later on, i set the first run to false? it will still get into the if statement and set back to YES

Answer (score 22):

you don't check.

you register your defaults. and if you haven't saved a value the default will be used.

```
NSDictionary *defaultUserDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], @"Foo",
                                     @"Bar", @"Baz",
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInteger:12], @"FooBar",
                                     nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultUserDefaults];
```

and you do this **every** time your app launches.

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe I missed that. +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

1. NSUserDefaults already exists by default. You can add to it by `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"object" forKey:@"key"];`
2. You can find the NSUserDefaults .plist here [image]