# iPhone NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios4, nsuserdefaults, nsfilemanager

I have stored some values in NSUserDefaults and now I need to check, using NSFileManager, whether a certain value exists in the defaults. If the value exsists then I need to skip some parsing, and display information in a tableview. Please help me figure out how to do this check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:...]
```

to retrieve the value.

Comment: i know that but how to do that with nsfile manager, means should check that file exsist in nslibrarydirectory.

Comment: Maybe Niels Castle's response from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676938/easy-way-to-see-saved-nsuserdefaults) helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSData instead NSFile manager

Get values from nsuserdefaults to nsData and check whether any values available in nsData, if yes then perform some activity else ignore.

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471830/why-nsuserdefaults-failed-to-save-nsmutabledictionary-in-iphone-sdk) is the link for the same discussion.

Hope this will help you.