# Where does OCUnit store NSUserDefaults?

Tags: nsuserdefaults, ocunit, sentestingkit

I read the question [Easy way to see saved NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676938/easy-way-to-see-saved-nsuserdefaults)

I found the .plist file for the app, but where's the one for the testing bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that OCUnit doesn't store `NSUserDefaults` persistently but rather in memory. But, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If you use Xcode 4's integration with OCUnit, it injects the test bundle into a running application. NSUserDefaults are therefore saved in the application itself. This is problematic for unit tests: When you run the app manually, your defaults may have been overwritten by your tests.

Instead of using `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` directly, use dependency injection, passing in user defaults as an initializer argument. Then you can pass in a test double that you can query. (An alternative to dependency injection is returning NSUserDefaults from a helper method, overriding that method to return the test double when necessary.)

Comment: Are you sure? I'm using XCode 4, but it seems that, with OCUnit, `NSUserDefaults` aren't being stored to the application's .plist file where `NSUserDefaults` are normally stored. Actually, I don't see them being stored at all. Although, I could be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

In my environment (Xcode 4.2, running tests in the simulator) `NSUserDefaults` writes to the following file:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/Library/Preferences/otest.plist`
```

I guess you didn't see the file because of `NSUserDefaults`'s caching mechanism (explained in the class reference), and because your project's unit tests do not run long enough for the caching time interval to elapse.

`otest.plist` is guaranteed to be written, though, if something invokes the `NSUserDefault` instance method `synchronize` while the tests are running.