# Is it possible to trace back a string inside an IPA binary?

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, ipa

I mean if I write something in the code:

```
NSString *myKey = @"this is my private key";
```

Will someone be able to trace back the string `"this is my private key"` from the IPA?

I ask this for the encryption in iPhone.

If I store my encrypt key in the code, is it already safe? or how should I do it?

Comment: It's not safe. hackers can get it from the sources if they want.

Comment: Further question:
Any way to keep a really "private key" within the app?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's likely.  An IPA is just a zip file.  You can extract it to get the application binary.  You can usually run `strings` over an application binary to see string literals.