# Where is NSUserDefaults saved during development?

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults

I'm using NSUserDefaults to save some data in my application. Where can I find the file where my data is stored during development? It's a normal cocoa app (so no ios/iphone!)

Once it's deployed, it should be available in Library/Preferences/appname.plist, right? But where can I find it while I'm still working on the application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to see saved NSUserDefaults?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676938/easy-way-to-see-saved-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: Not really a duplicate -- that one's about iOS, this one's about OS X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference between "development" and "deployment". NSUserDefaults doesn't know whether you did a debug or release build. The location should be `~/Library/Preferences/yourAppIdentifier.plist` no matter what.

If you are seeing a difference between development and deployment builds, maybe check the bundle identifier (`CFBundleIdentifier`) in your app's `Info.plist`.

Also: if your app is sandboxed, your prefs will end up in the sandbox: `~/Library/Containers/yourAppIdentifier/Data/Library/Preferences/yourAppIdentifier.plist`. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/MigratingALegacyApp/MigratingAnAppToASandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH6-SW1) claims that the system automatically moves your old preferences file into the sandbox, if necessary, on the first launch of the sandboxed version of the app.

Comment: My `CFBundleIdentifier` is `be.company.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`, but after running my application in xcode, I can't find anything starting with `be.` in either `HD/Llibrary` or `~/Library`. I also don't have a `~/Library/Containers` folder.

Comment: To be absolutely sure: check the `Info.plist` file in the _built_ app. Maybe something is messing it up.

Comment: It's correct in the Info.plist. Still nothing though. I'll just keep searching. At least I know where to look now.