# Storing results after screen is disappear

Tags: iphone

I am developing a game,in that i want to add the points continuously,for this i used plist but whenever the screen is disappear and starts then plist starts again.what to do?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to write the code for saving the game data in -(void)viewWillDisappear;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add more info to Ahmed's answer you should implement in your AppDelegate.m three methods like this:

**AppDelegate.h**

```
NSNumber *gamescore;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *gamescore;


#define UIAppDelegate \
   ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
@synthesize gamescore;

- (BOOL) checkFirstRun {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSNumber *defaultcheck;
    defaultcheck = [defaults objectForKey:@"GameScore"];
    if (defaultcheck==nil) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

- (void) storeGlobalVars {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:gamescore forKey:@"GameScore"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (void) readGlobalVars {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    gamescore = [defaults objectForKey:@"GameScore"];
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
// ...
    if ([self checkFirstRun]) {
    // first run, lets create basic default values

        gamescore = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        [self storeGlobalVars];
    } else {
        [self readGlobalVars];      
    }
// ...
```

Later in your application, after importing *AppDelegate.h* you can use the *UIAppDelegate.gamescore* to access the AppDelegate's property.

And you have to remember that gamescore is an *NSNumber* object, you have to manipulate it using *NSNumber*'s *numberWithInt* and/or *intValue*.

The *CheckFirstRun* is needed because your user's device at application first run doesn't contain the default plist and the initial values, you have to create an initial set.

Comment: but where i have to use the plist here

Comment: NSUserDefaults implicitly means a plist stored in your application bundle. You dont have to care, the framework will care how to access plist file

Comment: Please see to SO answer how to see this plist file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676938/easy-way-to-see-saved-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 0):

You can make AppDelegate variables and store it in them. There scope remains in the complete application until the application closes.

In AppDelegate.h
for example

```
NSString *string;

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *string;
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize string;
```

in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
string = @"";
```

And then is your classes
add `#import "AppDelegate.h"`

then in your code 
`((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication SharedApplication].Delegate).string = @"1";`

Comment: and no need to use plist at all

Comment: but i need if player get some points in this game like 10 then again in next game it is 20 n soon now hav to add all these 10,20 for this it will not works

Comment: you can use plist for that or you can NSUserDefaults for that to store it locally on device.

Comment: if you got waht you were looking for please accept the answer.. thank you. :)