# Is there a way to get all values in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, nsuserdefaults

I would like to print all values I saved via `NSUserDefaults` without supplying a specific Key.

Something like printing all values in an array using `for` loop. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: In your application's domain or the system domain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676938/easy-way-to-see-saved-nsuserdefaults

Comment: For Swift you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27534573/1497737

Answer (score 231, accepted):

**Objective C**

all values:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allValues]);
```

all keys:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys]);
```

all keys and values:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

using for:

```
NSArray *keys = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys];

for(NSString* key in keys){
    // your code here
    NSLog(@"value: %@ forKey: %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:key],key);
}
```

**Swift**

all values:

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().values)
```

all keys:

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys)
```

all keys and values:

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation())
```

Comment: Swift 3 all values: print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().values)                   all keys:     print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys)

Answer (score 6):

Print only keys

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys]);
```

Keys and Values

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *defaultAsDic = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation];
NSArray *keyArr = [defaultAsDic allKeys];
for (NSString *key in keyArr)
{
     NSLog(@"key [%@] => Value [%@]",key,[defaultAsDic valueForKey:key]);
}
```

Comment: quite understandable

Answer (score 4):

You can log all of the contents available to your app using:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```