# How to print NSUserDefaults content in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

How do you print all the content of NSUserDefaults?
I need to see everything that has been stored into NSUserDefaults. Is there a simple way to print that or to see it into the logs?

In Swift!

Thank you

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Taken from - [Retrieve UserDefaults in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27534573/1497737)

## In Swift we can use the following:-

## Swift 3.x & 4.x

#### For getting all keys & values:

```
for (key, value) in UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation() {
    print("\(key) = \(value) \n")
}
```

#### For retrieving the complete dictionary representation of user defaults:

```
print(Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()))
```

#### For retrieving the keys:

```
// Using dump since the keys are an array of strings.
dump(Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys))
```

#### For retrieving the values:

We can use dump here as well, but that will return the complete inheritance hierarchy of each element in the values array. If more information about the objects is required, then use dump, else go ahead with the normal print statement.

```
// dump(Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().values))
print(Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().values))
```

## Swift 2.x

#### For retrieving the complete dictionary representation of user defaults:

```
print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation())
```

#### For retrieving the keys:

```
print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys.array)
```

#### For retrieving the values:

```
print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().values.array)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for elem in NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation() {
    println(elem)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax in to get all standard user defaults in **Swift 3**

```
print(UserDefaults.standard().dictionaryRepresentation())
```

Answer (score 0):

With Swift 3.0

print(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation())

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax that provide more clarity.

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard    
defaults.dictionaryRepresentation().map{print("\($0.key): \($0.value)")}
```

Comment: i think forEach instead of map is more approriate