# How to initialize from the command line a value from the user defaults database for an iPhone app that is run on the simulator and/or a device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have an application that I can't modify (although I have the source code) that uses values from the [user default's system](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html) ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSUserDefaults/standardUserDefaults)) to configure some settings from the app.

I'm trying to create a command line script that builds the app with xcodebuild, and then launches the app directly into the iPhone simulator or a device. I'd like to be able to modify a value of the "user default's system" so when I lunch the app in either the iPhone simulator or an iPhone device, it'll start with the configuration that I want. How can I do that?

Things I've tried:

- **xcrun simctl spawn `<`simulator-device-id`>` defaults read** but the settings from my app doesn't appear there.
- Modifying ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//data/Containers/Data/Application/`<`app-id`>`/Library/Preferences/`<`app-name`>`.plist with /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy: This one seems to work partially, but I only can find this folder after I've run the app for the first time, and I haven't find any easy way to know what's the app-id of my app from my command line before actually running the app in the iphone simulator.
  Ideally, I'd like my app to run for the first time with the settings that I want to use, if I use the PlistBuddy options it seems I'll have to run it once to find the folder, and a second time to actually set the setting before running it.

Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would accomplish what you want.

If you launch an application in your simulator via `xcrun simctl launch <deviceid> <app identifier>`, you can provide arguments to the application.

```
xcrun simctl help launch
Usage: simctl launch [-w | --wait-for-debugger] <device> <app identifier> [<argv 1> <argv 2> ... <argv n>]

If you want to set environment variables in the resulting environment, set them in the calling environment with a SIMCTL_CHILD_ prefix.
```

The standard example of these parameters is for setting AppleLocale or AppleLanguages. But as long as you put a dash before an argument and follow it with an argument without a dash, that makes the first argument a key in your app's defaults, and the second argument will be the value.

For example, I have [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848980/3422145) in my `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in my app so that all of the defaults get printed:

```
NSLog(@"Defaults: %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

And on the command line I've entered:

```
xcrun simctl launch booted com.Myapp -AppleLanguages "(ru)" -variableFromCommandLineWithoutParameters -variableFromCommandLineWithParameter "hello"
```

Looking in the simulator's log, I find:

> Jan 25 18:27:46 AaronMacPro MyApp[70005]: Defaults: {
>
> ```
>   AddingEmojiKeybordHandled = 1;
>   AppleITunesStoreItemKinds =     (
>       audiobook,
>       "tv-episode",
>       booklet,
>       software,
>       "software-update",
>       "itunes-u",
>       ringtone,
>       "tv-season",
>       movie,
>       mix,
>       wemix,
>       song,
>       tone,
>       artist,
>       "podcast-episode",
>       podcast,
>       eBook,
>       document,
>       album,
>       "music-video"
>   );
>   AppleKeyboards =     (
>       "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",
>       "emoji@sw=Emoji",
>       "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY"
>   );
>   AppleKeyboardsExpanded = 1;
>   AppleLanguages =     (
>       ru
>   );
>   AppleLanguagesDidMigrate = "9.1";
>   AppleLocale = "en_US";
>   ApplePasscodeKeyboards =     (
>       "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY",
>       "emoji@sw=Emoji",
>       "en_US@hw=US;sw=QWERTY"
>   );
>   NSInterfaceStyle = macintosh;
>   NSLanguages =     (
>       ru,
>       en
>   );
>   variableFromCommandLineWithParameter = hello;
> ```
>
> }

That's a lot of spam, but if you scroll down, you can find the values I set. The `AppleLanguages` key has been filled in with "ru" instead of the default "en". My `variableFromCommandLineWithParameter` showed up with its value of "hello". My `variableFromCommandLineWithoutParameters` did not show up in any way.

I haven't used `xcrun simctl spawn` like you said you tried in your question, but according to the help text it also allows arguments like this if that's what you need.