# NSUserDefault , Alloc init vs standard Userdefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

i am confused  that what is difference between

`NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];`

and

`NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];`

can any one can help me......

thnx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

This is a class method will will return the shared instance of the NSUserDefaults. As it is a shared instance. It is the ideal place to store data at a global level, to access across your application.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
```

This is an instance method which will initialize an allocated instance of NSUserDefaults. As every-time this is called, a new instance is initialized and returned, this would not be useful to store data at a global level. Hence more suited when at an intra-class level. Also, this instance's lifetime will be valid only till its scope of reference is present.

More info here: [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSUserDefaults/standardUserDefaults)

To access standard defaults in Simulator/Device: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1677104/1740354)

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
> ```
>
> the above line gives you the **singleton object** by using the class
>   method standardUserDefaults the object received by this method is allocated single memory throughout the application.
>
> ```
> NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
> ```
>
> this will gives you the **new object**, each object is allocated a different 
>   memory and deallocated when object scope is finished.

***If you want to store and use the value throughout the application then its better to use singleton object and that will be deallocated when you delete your application***

Answer (score 1):

With standUserDefaults you are using the sharedInstance of the app. With alloc init you can make a new user defaults with an identifier. I used it once when I had to share data with my app's Share Extension. I saved data in User Defaults against my created Identifier to access in my Share Extension Project.

I believe there must be more explanation to it, you can look here
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/

Answer (score 1):

[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] will use global shared instance of Userdefaults.

standardUserDefaults returns a global instance of NSUserDefaults configured to search the current application's search list.

[[NSUserDefaults alloc]init] will create instance everytime.

Its better to use **[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]**

Comment: as i read userdefault are stored in .plist file if i create with **standradUserDefault** so it is accessible at application level and what if i used alloc init , is it stored in other location (not in same plist file)

Comment: No it does not get stored in the same plist.

Answer (score 0):

Based on NSUserDefaults.h description, when using the standardUserDefaults, **you will get a global instance of NSUserDefaults configured to search the current application's search list.**

While, if you use alloc init, you'll need a **suitename**.

-init is equivalent to -initWithSuiteName:nil