# App Group in Today's Extension Swift 3.0

Tags: ios-app-extension, today-extension, ios-app-group

I am developing a **Today's Extension** of an app. I am having some problems regarding **App Groups** that are used as `shared containers` between extension and containing app.

1. Where is the **App Group** data stored?
2. How to see what data is stored in the **App Group**?

Answer (score 1):

Shared Containers is simply a UserDefault dictionary that is shared between Extensions in an App. To store data in the container Init your container using the `suiteName` UserDefault:

```
let SharedDefaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.YOURGROUP")!
```

TheN to set a value, in this case a `String`:

```
SharedDefaults.set("something", forKey: "aKey")
```

And to retrieve the information (from either the Extension or App) use:

```
let myString = SharedDefaults.string(forKey: "aKey")
```

This explains how to to print the contents of the UserDefaults: [Easy way to see saved NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676938/easy-way-to-see-saved-nsuserdefaults/27534573#27534573)

Comment: I know how to use App Group. Please read the question carefully. I want to know where in the system App Group data is stored?