# How to remove UserDefaults data swift?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, keychain

userdaeults does not delete the data in memory, although I do delete it. Keychain does the deletion. I share the code below. It calls the handlelogout function when exiting. The recording is fine, but when I exit, it does not delete the data that I have saved.

```
 @objc func deleteee(){
        do {
            try keychain.remove("chipnumbernew")
        } catch let error {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }


    }

    @objc func deleteeetimer(){

        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "timertext")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "timertext2")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    }
 @objc func handleLogout(){

        do {
            deleteee()
            deleteeetimer()
            try Auth.auth().signOut()



            let mainTableVC = LoginViewController()

            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainTableVC)

            self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: {

                //
            })

        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print ("Giriş Yapılamadı: %@", signOutError)
        }
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let token = try? keychain.getString("chipnumbernew")
        chip1InfoString = token

        if let strtimer = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "timertext") {
            print("strtimer", strtimer)
          timertextNew.text = strtimer
        }

        if let strtimer2 = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "timertext2") {
            print("strtimer2", strtimer2)
            timertext2New.text = strtimer2

        } }
```

Comment: it's still in memory, it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `removeObject` in `UserDefaults` itself will clear the value. You can verify that directly in the plist. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676938/easy-way-to-see-saved-nsuserdefaults) post for accessing plist.

Still, you want to clean up, you can try below code.

```
    if let appDomain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
        UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: appDomain)
    }
```